# Bump Mapping in OpenGL ES 2.0/GLKit?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a project that displays a number of rotating cubes and would like to learn more about bump and displacement maps. I have a brief understanding of how they work and have already chosen my textures and bump maps by using Crazy Bump beta.

The only tutorial that I have found so far is in the book Pro OpenGL ES for iOS by Mike Smithwick, but it only covers OpenGL ES 1, and I've just got the hang of GLKit; I am able to add textures to my cubes, blended colours and a finger guided spotlight.

Is there a tutorial or guide anybody can point me to that may have more information on how to blend textures and bump maps in OpenGL ES 2?